# html css dropdown menu not working

Tags: html, css

im just trying to make an ordinary dropdown menu but its not working i cant find problem help

```css
.nava {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.nava li a {
  color: #e30a17;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}
.minecraft:hover .nava {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#" class="minecraft">Minecraft İçerikleri<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i></a>
  <ul class="nava">
    <li><a href="#">Modlar</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Kaynak Paketleri</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this code

```
.minecraft:hover + .nava {
  display: block;
}
```